"error": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'" when trying to decode the message in the file
I've been working on a project that embeds ciphertext into a PNG file using LSB. My lsb_encode function works, the IV is correctly saved in the metadata (I've checked) and overall the file is usable. My main issue is when I try to reverse the process. I get the error in the title using this curl command -> curl -X POST -F "encoded_image=@C:/Users/PATH/output_image.png" -F "delimiter=example delimiter" ``http://127.0.0.1:5000/png_decode. I have been stuck on this part of the issue for a couple of days now. I am not a developer and this is one of my first 'major' projects I've been working on so any lead is welcome!
import logging
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, PngImagePlugin, JpegImagePlugin
import hashlib
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
import io
from io import BytesIO
import os
from flask import Flask, url_for, jsonify, send_file, request
# Code is test only right now. IF it works as intended it should be tuned to adapt to a web service.

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

master_key = 'swlLZ3oalZ5w_sk9ZCgUgmkH7PZLJQqt76D51a5kdAM='


#@app.route('/png_encode', methods=['POST'])
def lsb_encoder(file, message, delimiter, iv):
    # image load and convert to array
    try:
        with Image.open(file) as img:
            if img.mode != 'RGB':
                img = img.convert('RGB')
            encoded_image = img.copy()
            width, height = img.size
            logging.debug("Image size: %dx%d", width, height)


        #Prepare binary message including delimiter
        binary_message = ''.join(format(byte, '08b') for byte in message)
        binary_delimiter = ''.join(format(byte, '08b') for byte in delimiter)
        binary_message += binary_delimiter
        logging.debug("Binary message length in bits: %d", len(binary_message))

        # Check if message fits in image
        if len(binary_message) > width * height * 3:
            return None, jsonify({"error": "Message cannot be fully hidden in image"})

        pixels = encoded_image.load()
        message_index = 0
        
        # Encode message into image
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                if message_index >= len(binary_message):
                    break

                r, g, b = pixels[x, y]

                for i in range(3):
                    if message_index >= len(binary_message):
                        break

                    bit = int(binary_message[message_index])
                    if i == 0:
                        r = (r & ~1) | bit
                    elif i == 1:
                        g = (g & ~1) | bit
                    else:
                        b = (b & ~1) | bit

                    message_index += 1

                pixels[x, y] = (r, g, b)

        output_buffer = io.BytesIO()
        png_info = PngImagePlugin.PngInfo()
        png_info.add_text("iv", iv.hex())
        encoded_image.save(output_buffer, pnginfo=png_info, format="PNG", optimize=False) # compress_level=0 If facing image size related errors, set optimize to False
        output_buffer.seek(0)
        logging.debug("Encoded image size after saving %d KB", output_buffer.tell()//1024)
        return output_buffer, None

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error during encoding: %s", e)
        return None, jsonify({"error": "Failed to process and encode image"})
    
    
#########################################################################################################################################################################

#@app.route('/png_decode', methods=['POST'])
def lsb_decoder(file):
    try:
        file.seek(0)
        with Image.open(file) as img:
            logging.debug("Image opened successfully in lsb_decoder.")
            if img.mode != 'RGB':
                img = img.convert('RGB')
            width, height = img.size
            logging.debug("Encoded image size: %dx%d", width, height)
        
        pixels = img.load()
        binary_message = ''
        
        # Extract LSB bits to form binary string
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                r, g, b = pixels[x, y]
                binary_message += str(r & 1)
                binary_message += str(g & 1)
                binary_message += str(b & 1)

        # Convert binary string to bytes
        binary_message = [binary_message[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(binary_message), 8)]
        message_bytes = bytearray()
        
        for byte in binary_message:
            if len(byte) < 8:
                continue  # Skip if not a full byte
            message_bytes.append(int(byte, 2))
        # Return the extracted bytes (ciphertext + delimiter), without IV
        return bytes(message_bytes), None
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error during extraction: %s", e)
        return None, str(e)

    # return jsonify({"message": decoded_message}), 200

@app.route('/png_encode', methods=['POST'])
def data_preprocessing():
    file = request.files.get('image') #get image from upload
    message = request.form.get('message') #get message to be stegoed into image
    delimiter = request.form.get('delimiter') #get delimiter to be hashed for derived key and stegoed in the image
    
    if not file or not message or not delimiter:
        return jsonify({"error": "Image, message and delimiter are required"}), 400

    hashed_delimiter = hashlib.sha256(delimiter.encode('utf8')).digest() #hash delimiter
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32, #32 bytes = 256 bit key for AES-256
        salt = hashed_delimiter,
        iterations=10000,
        backend=default_backend()
        )#derive key for encryption of message
    derived_key = kdf.derive(master_key.encode('utf8'))
    
    message_bytes = message.encode('utf8')
    #AES cipher in CBC mode
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(derived_key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
    #Padding to make it multiple of 16 bytes
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
    padded_message = padder.update(message_bytes) + padder.finalize()
    #Encrypt the padded message
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    ciphertext = encryptor.update(padded_message) + encryptor.finalize()
    
    encoded_image, error_response = lsb_encoder(file, ciphertext, hashed_delimiter, iv) #error_response
    if error_response:
        return error_response
    
    return send_file(encoded_image, mimetype="image/png", as_attachment=True, download_name="encoded_image.png")

@app.route('/png_decode', methods=['POST'])
def data_deciphering():
    encoded_image = request.files.get('encoded_image')  # Get the encoded image from upload
    delimiter = request.form.get('delimiter')  # Get the delimiter used for hashing

    if not encoded_image or not delimiter:
        return jsonify({"error": "Image and delimiter are required"}), 400

    hashed_delimiter = hashlib.sha256(delimiter.encode('utf8')).digest()  # Hash the delimiter

    # Decode the image to extract the ciphertext and delimiter (IV not included here)
    ciphertext_with_delimiter, error_response = lsb_decoder(encoded_image)
    if error_response:
        return jsonify({"error": error_response}), 400

    # Extract IV from image metadata in data_deciphering
    try:
        with Image.open(encoded_image) as img:
            iv_hex = img.info.get("iv", None)
            if iv_hex is None:
                return jsonify({"error": "IV not found in image metadata"}), 400
            iv = bytes.fromhex(iv_hex)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error reading IV from image metadata: %s", e)
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to extract IV from image"}), 400

    # Derive key for decryption
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,  # 32 bytes = 256 bit key for AES-256
        salt=hashed_delimiter,
        iterations=10000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    derived_key = kdf.derive(master_key.encode('utf8'))
    
    # AES cipher in CBC mode for decryption
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(derived_key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

    # Decrypt the ciphertext
    padded_message = decryptor.update(ciphertext_with_delimiter) + decryptor.finalize()
    
    # Unpadding to get the original message
    unpadder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()
    original_message = unpadder.update(padded_message) + unpadder.finalize()
    message_length = len(original_message) - 32
    original_message = original_message[:message_length].decode('utf8')
    return jsonify({"message": original_message}), 200


#########################################################################################################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Added several logging statements to try and track where the process fails but to no avail.

This error means you're trying to use a variable that's not been initialized as you expect: it's None instead of the object you want. Most likely here, encoded_image = request.files.get('encoded_image') is not finding what you want and giving your None. You need to check for that situation before continuing in the code.
